# c# how to update model based on other model with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model linq select:

```
List<EmployeeProfile> employee = DL.GetEmployeeProfile(id);

        var result = employee.Select(a => new[]
        {
            a.EmployeeName,
            a.EmployeeId.Tostring(),
            a.View.ToString(),
            a.Edit.ToString(),
            a.Block.ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

This list can has about 100 records.

Then I have this class:

```
public class EmployeeSelection
    {

        public Int64 employeeId{ get; set; }
        public bool view { get; set; }
        public bool edit { get; set; }
        public bool block{ get; set; }
    }
```

And I fill from json about 50 records so I have:

```
List<EmployeeSelection> employeeSelect = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeSelection>>(selection);
```

What I need is to update `result` list overwriting View, Edit or Block values from the `employeeSelect` list for the `employeeId` match.

> Any clue?

Comment: Start building `result` as an `IEnumerable<EmployeeSelection>`. That's a minor change.

Comment: result is result from other model. Let me update that

Answer (score 0):

try thins linq query out:

```
var newResult= from empl in result
         join sel in employeeSelect
         on empl.EmployeeId equals sel.employeeId.ToString()
                    select new EmployeeProfile {
                         EmployeeId = empl.EmployeeId,
                         EmployeeName = empl.EmployeeName,
                         Edit = sel.edit.ToString(),
                         Block = sel.block.ToString(),
                         View = sel.view.ToString()
                     };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just join the two lists together and use just the employee selection object to fill in with the new details

```
var employeeProfiles = DL.GetEmployeeProfile(id);

var employeeSelect = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeSelection>>(selection);

var result = employeeProfiles.Join(employeeSelect,
    profile => profile.EmployeeId,
    selection => selection.employeeId,
    (x, y) => new EmployeeProfile
    {
        EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,  
        Block = y.block,
        Edit = y.edit,
        EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName,
        View = y.view
    });
```